# How to access private (underscore) identifiers in the same library but in a different file

Tags: dart

According to dart.dev, "If an identifier starts with an underscore (_), it’s private to its library.". This should mean that separate files using the same library directive should be able to see private identifiers in the other ones, right? For instance:

other.dart:

```dart
library mylib;

const _foo = 42;
```

main.dart:

```dart
library mylib;

import 'other.dart';

void main() {
  print(_foo); // Error: Getter not found: '_foo'.
}
```

What am I doing or understanding wrong here?

Comment: I believe Dart has reflection capabilities.  Look into that keyword.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dart and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178771/dart-and-underscores)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a duplicate of [Dart and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178771/dart-and-underscores) as suggested, that question itself (rather than one of its answers) did include a clue for answering this one. You need to use the part/part of directives to accomplish what I was trying to do. dart.dev [mentions them](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages) but seems so determined to discourage their use that it refuses to even begin to explain how they work, so see [dart import and part of directives in same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238279/dart-import-and-part-of-directives-in-same-file) for a brief explanation.